# $ X_n = 2 Y_n + Y_{n+1} $ (non)Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Let $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ be iid random variables with $P(Y_n=0)=1-p,\; P(Y_n=1)=p$ where $p\in(0,1)$. Define
>   $$ X_n = 2 Y_n + Y_{n+1} $$
>   The question is, whether $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov chain or not.

This is a homework question. The implication is that it is **not** a Markov chain, since it was given as a counterexample against common intuition ("I see $n$ and $n+1$ in the definition, it's gotta be a Markov chain!")

**My idea:** It seems like the value of $X_n$ uniquely determines the values of $Y_n$ and $Y_{n+1}$, as each possible value ($0,1,2,$ or $3$) has a specific combination of $Y$'s that yield that combination. Thus it seems to me that the probability of different outcomes of $X_{n+1}$ is uniquely determined by $X_n$ regardless of the previous history, which points towards being a Markov chain.

Now I don't like spoiling the fun of finding the answer myself. But I've literally never encountered a problem that left me so clueless, usually I am at least aware of my lack of understanding.

So, please, **I do not want a complete answer**. I'd like to be reassured that I am indeed missing something elementary and perhaps just nudged in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Let $u(0)=u(2)=0$ and $u(1)=u(3)=1$, then $$X_{n+1}=2u(X_n)+Y_{n+2},$$ where $Y_{n+2}$ is independent of $(X_k)_{k\leqslant n}$, hence $(X_n)$ is Markov.